# Cannot run macro error when clicking Options menu. No workbook is open

Tags: excel

Description/Steps to reproduce:

- I open Excel directly via the Start Menu entry (e.g I haven't clicked on an existing xls file or anything)
- I am greeted with the start page. No workbook is open
- I click "Options"

I get the following errors repeated a few times:

- Cannot run the macro 'OnLoad'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.
- Cannot run the macro 'RibbonGetText'...
- Cannot run the macro 'RibbonGetSelectedItemID'...
- Cannot run the macro 'showTDTab'...

After I click OK on all the errors, eventually I can open the Options screen.

Steps I have tried:

- Repair install
- Uninstall/Reinstall
- In "Options/Add-ins" and removed all "Active Application Add-ins"
- In "Trust Center/Add-ins" and clicked "Disable all Application Add-ins"
- In "Trust Center" I temporarily set "Enable VBA macros (not recommended)" but the error still continued, so set back to "Disable VBA macros with notification"

Excel version: 2016 Version 2209

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

All the info I can find focuses on Macros IN a workbook. I don't even have a workbook open, I'm just trying to get to the Excel Options screen.

Comment: Do you have an Excel add-in loaded? or a Personal.XLSB?

Comment: @BigBen As mentioned already, I had removed all add-ins and additionally set "Disable all add-ins". I haven't heard of XLSB before, I'll go read about it